# I am finding an error that my drop down list isn't coming on the webpage

Tags: php, mysql, html, mysqli

I want to make a drop down list on my webpage from the database. I made a php file d2.php which has the following code :

```
<?php 
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "") 
or  die("Connection    Failed");
$db= mysqli_select_db($con,"csv_db")or die("Connection Failed");  
?>
<select name="to_user" class="form-control">
<option value="pick">radio</option>
<?php
$sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT DISTINCT COL1 FROM TABLE2");
$row = mysqli_num_rows($sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
{
echo "<option value='". $row['COL1'] ."'>" .$row['COL1'] ."</option>" ;
}
?>
</select>
```

I added a drop list with href=d2.php in the html file. But the drop down list comes on the next page after clicking on the tag on the webpage. I want it to be on the same page. How to do this ?

Comment: `$db`, `$con`, are you sure what are you doing?

Comment: omg, put the db rules into other file or just in the head of that file, calling the functions of mysqli through your code. To stay in the same page, redirect to your same code filtering with conditional

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this field isn't going to be reloaded based on other form input then the simple solution is to include the php file where you want the select field:

```
<?php include('d2.php'); ?>
```